# Is $\mu_n$ and $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ the same thing?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, etale-cohomology

As a $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$-module (not a sheaf), I know that the roots of unity $\mu_n$ is noncanonically isomorphic to the $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$. Also the [nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Tate+twist) says that it is also so in the $\ell$-adic case. But I've been told that the étale sheaf $\mu_n$ defined by the Kummer sequence $$0\to\mu_n\to\mathscr{O}_X^*\overset{(-)^n}{\to}\mathscr{O}_X^*\to0$$ is not (even noncanonically) isomorphic to the constant sheaf $\underline{\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}}_X$ without further explanation. Can you elucidate the last statement for me?

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}_X$ has a canonical, never-vanishing, global section. But $\mu_n(X)$ is $\{t \in O(X),\, t^n=1\}$ – depending on what $X$ is, this need not contain any nonzero global section.

Answer (score 3):

As explained in the comment, they might have non-isomorphic global sections. In fact, we can say a little bit more. Namely, both group schemes are representable. For simplicity, I take $X=Spec(R)$.

- $\underline{\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}}_X$ is representable by the ring $R^n$
- $(\mu_{n})_X$ is representable by the ring $R[x]/(x^n-1)$

So for these two to be isomorphic, it is necessary (and in fact sufficient) that $R$ contains all $n$-th roots of unity (for example $k$ an algebraically closed field of characteristic coprime to $n$), which need not be the case.

It fact, here is an extreme case: Let's assume $n$ is prime and $n=0$ in $R$. Then $R[x]/(x^n-1)\cong R[x]/(x-1)^n$. So it will be actually a connected non-reduced group scheme (which is basically as far from being a constant sheaf as it can be). In terms of functors it implies that $\mu_n(Y)=1$ for any reduced scheme $Y$, whereas $\underline{\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}}_X(Y)=\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}^{\pi_0(Y)}$.

Comment: The story I heard is that the representation of fundamental group they induce are different: $Z/nZ$ induces the trivial one and $\mu_n$ induces the cyclotomic one, so the two sheaves contain different "monodromy information" and thus are different. Do you know anything about these?

Comment: Also, in the finite or separably closed case, is the Tate twist (tensoring with $\mu_n$) just the identity functor?

Comment: @SayakoHoshimiya Both $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mu_n$ are locally constant sheaves and the category of locally constant sheaves is equivalent to the category of representations of $\pi_1$. You indeed gave the corresponding representations which are non isomorphic (unless the cyclotomic representation is trivial which happens iff $X$ contains every $n$-th roots of unity) thus the corresponding sheaves are non isomorphic (unless $X$ contains every $n$-th roots of unity).